# Detecting Sentence Boundry

Tags: complex-sentences

Lets say someone writes a message like:

**Bob: You are my best friend Daniel Nelsion: You have helped me a lot**

How can this type of written messages be separated as :

1. **Bob: You are my best friend**
2. **Daniel Nelsion: You have helped me a lot**

Will it need machine learning ?
If Yes, supervised learning or unsupervised learning.

Comment: The question is unanswerable. It depends entirely on what kind of parsing system you are using.

Comment: @ColinFine Can you elaborate how this problem depends on parsing system being used ?